# yii2 join model as dataProvider

Tags: yii2

I've joined 2 tables like following:
    
    `$model = SalesEntry::find()
    ->joinWith('salesItems')
    ->all();`

then in view used DataProvider like following:
    
    `GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model,
    'columns' => [
    'date', // sample field from first table to see if ok
    ],
    ]);`

and I’ve got following error:

> Call to a member function getCount() on a non-object

What  am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because an `ActiveQuery` instance is not a `DataProvider`, which the widget expects. You need to wrap it in an `ActiveDataProvider` for it to work:

```
GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $model]),
   ' columns' => [
      'date', // sample field from first table to see if ok
   ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

DataProvider in GridView should be an instance of `yii\data\DataProviderInterface`

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$dataProvider-detail).